# How to import .csv file data into mysql table using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Good day everyone, I just want to know how to import .csv file data into mysql table using vb.net.

example:
1. Using open file dialog to open the .csv file.
2. A textbox to display the .csv filename.
3. And a button to insert .csv data into mysql table.

Note: .csv contains name and address field as well the mysql table.

Thanks in advance if someone can help.

Comment: The magic happens here: `insert .csv data into mysql table`.  Please read [Ask] carefully and also take the [Tour]

Comment: There is information for this all over the internet and this site, what have you tried? What are you struggling with? I would read the .csv to a DataSet and then use this to update the database.